# Is it a sin to setup a ring tune to caller tune on a incoming calls

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sharia, source-identification

I want to ask a question to an Islamic Scholar.
Please define us, is it a **sin** to set a ring tune as an **incoming calls tune**?

Comment: Salam you say "I want to ask a question to an Islamic Scholar. " then why are you asking it here? None in this site claims to be a scholar.

Comment: Yes dear, there are too many Islamic Scholar's are available here, Stackoverflow have many Scholar' here just see and search them

Comment: @raoabdullah07 You have to educate yourself regarding the definition of a Islamic scholar.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no.

But if you could, perhaps switch the tune to something Islamic based like the Adthan, Quran recitation, or even a nasheed.

As far as I’m aware, there are ring tones the sounds of birds, nature, and there’s the occasionally flash too where your phone would light up if there’s a call (I think, not too sure if that’s only for phone notifications).

All in all, it’s not like you’ll be listening to it for fun, it’s just to notify you someone is calling you.

Comment: Generally I Think so it's not good to implement the ringtone on your cellphone like Islamic Adaan(Azaan), Hadith or Ayaah. Because When they alarmed or ringing we took our calls and the Adaan or Haidth cut off due to attending the calls

Comment: @raoabdullah07 then stick to sounds of nature